# is there a function that can I use in condition to say (if a varaible was sent) so do something Anylogic

Tags: java, anylogic

I would like to do a condition in my simulation that says (if the quantityToOrder was sent, then the currentStock decrement by the quantityToOrder value)
I didn't know how to do it in Anylogic.

[screenshot of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zsh1J.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not do it like that. Condition-based modelling is very error-prone (same for state chart conditions).

Instead, wherever you send your orders off, you reduce the `currentStock` by the `quantityOrdered`

At that point, you can easily add if-conditions to check if you want to order in the first place, like:

```
if(weatherIsNice()) {
    currentStock -= qtyOrdered;
}
```

Comment: well, my issue is for this (weatherIsNice) I  can't translated to Java language in Anylogic [ so in the condition box, should I write like that: quantityToOrder() ]

Comment: Do not use a condition box... Best clarify your actual question, not sure I understand. See here for some tips: https://www.benjamin-schumann.com/blog/2021/4/1/how-to-win-at-anylogic-on-stackoverflow